# I'm trying to make a dropdown menu like facebook

Tags: javascript

I want to make a dropdown menu like facebook. (Where Log out, Account Settings, Privacy Settings, etc. are located.). I've tried it, but couldn't make just 1 easy step. When I click the body text I want that dropdown menu to disappear. Can you post a code for that. Can it be something like this?

```
<div onclick="hideshow()"><a>DropdownMenu</a></div>
```

and I want that function that hideshow() function can anyone post it for me ? I'd really appreciate that.

This is because I'm noob at javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could, when the menu opens, not only show the menu, but also a full-page transparant layover. The page could be z-index 1, the layover z-index 2 and the menu z-index 3. Have the layover capture the onclick and hide the menu.

Answer (score 0):

gahmarjobah,

Are you opposed to using a Javascript library like [jQuery?](http://jquery.org)

If not, take a look at this example I made for you on jsfiddle.

[http://jsfiddle.net/zzr84/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/zzr84/4)

Comment: It is done on click, via jQuery click() function. This will remove the javascript from the design elements, so you can change the design without worrying about the script.

Comment: oh yes I figured it out, but I want this script to make this red background dropdown menu dissapear while I click on body everywhere. In examples it didn't work